# How do I make a button in the iPhone SDK that will look like the UIActionSheet buttons?

Tags: iphone, uiview

In some iPhone apps, I've seen buttons that look similar to UIActionSheet buttons (example: End Call button in Phone.app).

I would like one in a UIView that I've made.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply a UIButton with a scaled image attacked to it. Check out Apple's *UICatalog* example code, it has one of those buttons in blue. It is a simple technique.